# Find the area of the portion of the unitary sphere that lies inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Find the area of the portion of the unitary sphere that lies inside the cylinder

$x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parametrization of the unit sphere centered at the origin is given by: 
$$
\vec{r}(\phi,\theta) = \langle \sin \phi \cos \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta,\cos \phi\rangle,
$$
where $0\leq \phi\leq \pi/6$ and $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ since the two surfaces intersect when they are set equal to each other: 
$$
x^2+ y^2+ z^2 = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + z^2 =1. 
$$
This implies that $z=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, which implies that $\cos \phi=\frac{\mbox{adjacent}}{\mbox{hypotenuse}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}/2}{1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. So $\phi=\pi/6$.

Since $\vec{N}=\vec{r}_{\phi}\times \vec{r}_{\theta}=\sin\phi\langle \sin \phi \cos \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta,\cos \phi \rangle$, 
$|\vec{N}|=\sin \phi$. Note that since $0\leq \phi\leq \pi/6$, $|\sin \phi|=\sin \phi$.

Now, let's denote the top portion of the unit sphere which is contained in the cylinder $S_1$ and let's denote the bottom portion of the unit sphere which is inside the cylinder $S_2$. Let $S=S_1\cup S_2$.

Then the surface area $SA(S)$ of $S$ is: 
\begin{align*}
SA(S) 
&= \iint_S 1 \, dS \\
&= 2 \iint_{S_1} 1 \,dS   \\ 
&= 2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/6} 1 |\vec{r}_{\phi}\times \vec{r}_{\theta}| \,d\phi d\theta \\ 
&=  2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/6} 1 \sin \phi\, d\phi d\theta \\ 
&= 2(2\pi)(-\cos \phi)\Big|_0^{\pi/6} \\ 
&=4\pi\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+1\right) \\ 
&=2\pi(2 - \sqrt{3}). 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The standard area integration result/ formula (Archimedes) for a spherical cap area is

$$2 \pi R h $$

[image: polar caps]

angle between axis and diagonal = $30^0$

We have two polar caps, $R=1$, total area is

$$ 2 \pi R \cdot 2( 1 - \cos 30^0) = 2 \pi (2-\sqrt 3) $$